# Need a faceted visualization with custom axis positions

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization

Needed a faceted visualization for my personal project. Was looking for options over the web, found out https://github.com/chartshq/muze suits my purpose.

Though I was able to get started pretty early using their documentation, I faced a roadblock soon. Looks like the documentation in progress.

Here is a scaled down sample of what I have achieved so far
https://jsfiddle.net/q8w47vt1/

```js
Promise.all([
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chartshq/muze/master/examples/data/cars.json'),
  fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chartshq/muze/master/examples/data/cars-schema.json')]).then((response) => {
    Promise.all(response.map(_ => _.json())).then((res) => {
        const data = res[0]
        const schema = res[1];

        let DataModel = muze.DataModel;
        let rootData = new DataModel(data, schema);
        let env = muze(); 
        let canvas = env.canvas();

        canvas
            .rows(['Origin', 'Acceleration']) 
            .columns(['Cylinders']) 
            .data(rootData)
            .width(500)
            .height(500)
            .title('Acceleration by Cylinders by Origin')
            .subtitle('For years 1970 - 1982')
            .mount('#chart-container');
    });
});
```

**But, I wanted my visualization to have the axis on the right hand side and facet on the left of the plot and not on the left hand side. I tried a couple of ways to do it but was unable to achieve the result.**

Spent some time looking at the code, but couldnt figure out much, as I didnt have time to go through the codebase.

Can anyone help me on this? Dont want to raise issue right at this point of time, as I am not sure its a valid feature or not!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Changing the position of axis can be done like [below](https://jsfiddle.net/7chs05fe/)

```
 canvas.rows([[], ['Origin', 'Acceleration']])
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://www.charts.com/muze/docs/rows-columns-and-layout-variations#repositioning-the-axis)

Answer (score 0):

While the above configuration will serve your purpose to have the axis on the right hand side, it will shift the faceting to the right as well. You can choose to have your facets on the left-hand side of the canvas, while maintaining the axes to the right by providing the configuration as provided [below](https://jsfiddle.net/9zxnftjy/):

```html
canvas.rows([['Origin'],['Acceleration']])
```

Basically, the first array for the `rows` API provides the left hand side of the visualization and the second array provides the right hand side. If only a single array is provided, Muze automatically puts all the facets and axes to the left hand side of the visualization.

However, this may not be valid in some cases(specially, when you have only provided only dimensions to the API).

So, you may wish to checkout the documentation to understand how this API works for a better understanding [here](https://www.charts.com/muze/docs/rows-columns-and-layout-variations)